# Trying to upload image from my iOS app to server

Tags: php, ios, image, upload

I have the following problem - I am trying to upload an image to server from my iOS app, but I don't know how to do that. There is HTML form on that site that has button for browsing images. Within my app, I select a photo from the gallery, than I try to upload it, but nothing happens. I use this code to get things work, but with no positive result:

```
-(IBAction)postImage:(id)sender
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(savedImage, 90);

// setting up the URL to post to
NSString *urlString = @"http://pik.bg/news/edit_news/124317";

// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *requestUpload = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[requestUpload setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[requestUpload setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[requestUpload addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

 //now lets create the body of the post

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Filedata\" filename=\"IMG_0056.JPG\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[requestUpload setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web



 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestUpload returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog (@"%@", returnString);
    }
```

I am doing something wrong, but don't know what exactly. Any ideas? Oh, the HTML form has SUBMIT button with name "submit", if this is important.

Answer (score 0):

please let me know you are trying to upload only Image name or path of the image?
that is imageg1.png or UIImage object?
Actually I don't have permission to give a comment to question,so I had ask that in answer space.

Comment: I know.But we want 50 reputation to give a comment for any question.Ignore this.

Comment: I am using UIImage. I am doing it like this:
        UIImage *savedImage;
        savedImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        savedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
to pick an image from the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://........./";


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];

    UIImage * image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"good_girl.jpg"] autorelease];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
    [request setPostBody:imageData];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to do it the way I am trying. With no other frameworks, libraries and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that should be the solution for you.

In your server you should have a script with different parameters, among them a folder name.
Navigate to the right folder, and create this folder (for example images/). After that your images sent from your application will be saved in in this folder.

That was my problem when i used this method.

Comment: Okay, I will have a look at the PHP code. One more question:

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Filedata\" filename=\"IMG_0056.JPG\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Does it matter what filename I will set or it has to be the name of my current image that I picked from gallery? Because I don't know how to view my current image name.

Comment: For That you can do as bellow:

NSString *stringData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filedata\"; filename=\%@.jpg\r\n",self.textField.text];

Comment: Why do I need this textField !? I want to know if this filename is the name of my current picture or it's just some name?

Comment: Not, absolutly not, this means that your file name will have a name in your server (supposing that you have a textfield in your app) textfield.jpg

Comment: Can you tell me what do you have on this url ?
http://pik.bg/news/edit_news/124317

Comment: Yes, here is a picture of it - http://i.imgur.com/LG9vtgD.png

Two text fields, button for browsing images and submit button. I still can't upload image, it only fills the textfields with my text.

Comment: The URLString Variable must have your script which is located on your server. What are you trying to do will not work like that